# IOS : Make entire view scrollable, not only subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a viewController in which I have a scrollView in which I have 3 views. This is a scheme :

- ScrollView (UIScrollView)

  - Header (UIView)
  - TabBar (UIView)
  - Container (UIView in which I load a ViewController)

The main problem is that, in my container (in which there is a view controller), I have a collectionView (which can scroll) but I want my entire scrollView to scroll (not only my container).

So this is what I have :

[image: Only the Container is scrolling]

And this is what I want :
[image: I want the entire scrollView to scroll]

Anyone can help me with this ?

Comment: Are you able to view the contents inside the container i.e. the view controller inside it?

Comment: If you start the scroll gesture on either the *Header* or the *TabBar* - does the entire view scroll?

Comment: @iphondroid Yes, I'm able to view the contents inside the container. And if the content is greater than the view, I can scroll the elements inside the container view

Comment: @GavinHope No, I cannot scroll the view when I start the scroll gesture on Header or TabBar view. I can only scroll when I start the scroll gesture on Container but it is only the container view that scroll

Comment: How are you creating the view(s)? Interface Builder? Code? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @GavinHope The 3 views are added in the interface builder but the subviews of these views are created programmatically. Moreover, everything loads perfectly... The only problem is the scroll...

Comment: Hey! did you ever fix this problem, I have asked a very similar question! If you did fix it, could you please let me know how?! it's driving me crazy!

Comment: Hi guys, could you help me with my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797508/twitter-profile-effect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem for my own project. Assuming you are using storyboards, I made the UIView a child of UITableView and made the UITableView extend the full viewport of the device.

Since UITableView implements UIScrollView you get full screen scrolling of your content.

**General Rule** your parent view has to implement UIScrollView and extend the full screen to get viewport vertical scrolling.

[image: Hierarchy of TableView]

Answer (score 0):

To do this, if you are not using auto layout or if you are adding views to container programmatically, you must manually set collection view frame to match its content size after you load some data on it. If you are using auto layout, you should create height constraint outlet and set its constant value based on collection view content size, again after loading data on it

Answer (score 0):

You should set the frame of the container view to match the height of the view controller that it is loaded in it and set the contentsize of the scroolview based on the container height.

Comment: I agree with this approach and additionally, you can use a protocol to inform the "parent" view controller when the child "container" scrolls and then move the tab bar and header appropriately.

Comment: @FabioSalata When I do containerView.frame = controller.view.frame  and scrollView.contentSize.height = containerView.frame.height my Header and TabBar don't appear :s

Comment: @user3369214 you have to sum all views height not only the containerview

Comment: @FábioSalata It looks good (even though it dosent load every cells of my collectionview) but I think I must actualise the height of the "Container" every time a cell (in the viewcontroller) is load BUT now, even though I can scroll and see my cells, I cannot click on the cells that are not shown before I scroll... :(

Answer (score 0):

**A scrollview will scroll only if its contents are bigger than its frame.** This applies to the parent scrollview as well as the child scrollview. 
Here in your case, for the parent scrollview to scroll its contents (Header, Tabbar & container) together must have greater height than its parent. The child scrollview (container) is already scrolling because its contents (a view controller) has greater height than its parent.

I have made both scroll views to scroll:

(1) The parent scrollview -  by increasing the height of the child scrollview so that it extends below the main view controller's frame. The child scrollview is one of the contents of the main scrollview.

(2) The child scrollview - Setting a large content inside it so that it is bigger than its parent. I have used a long UIImage as its content.

Also, **I have used autolayout and pinned the contents to the scrollviews' sides by adding constraints.**

Hope this helps.

This is how it scrolls: [Scrolling of UIScrollView inside another](https://youtu.be/J5Qu9gEOJdc)